# Is it possible to select multiple files iOS device files in Finder in macOS Catalina?

Tags: ios, finder

In macOS Mojave, I could access my iOS/iPadOS device's files through iTunes by selecting my device in the sidebar and using the Files tab. I could select multiple files at the same time by selecting the first file, holding down shift, and selecting the last file.

In macOS Catalina, this functionality has moved to the Finder. I can select my device in the Finder sidebar, select the Files tab, and select a file. However, holding down shift to select multiple files doesn't seem to work anymore. I select my first file, hold down shift, then select my last file, but that just selects the last file.

Is it simply no longer possible to select multiple files? Is this a deliberate change or a Finder bug? The reason I want to do this is to be able to easily delete multiple files at the same time, ideally hundreds at a time. The iOS Files app allows me to select multiple files, but I still have to tap on each one individually, which is still more time consuming that I would like.